# Put java files in source control (git) when working from eclipse

Tags: java, git, version-control

If I have an eclipse java project and I want to put my source code under control what is the proper way to do it in git?
My source files are under Worspace/ProjectName/src as typically in an eclipse set up.
Should I move the files to another directory where I will do a `git init`? Or should I do a `git init` in `Worspace/ProjectName/src`? I am not clear what is the recommended/usual approach.

Comment: It's totally up to you. I usually make the workspace a git repo with the appropriate folders in the `.gitignore` file, but that's hardly the only way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do a git init in the workspace directory because eclipse detects the git repo in its workspace(if any)
and thereby allows you to manage(index, commit, push, pull, merge, rebase, fetch) your repo through [plugin (egit)](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) without even bothering to open the terminal.
It definitely gives you a joy and ease of working in IDE.

But still depends how you want to manage your project, there many ways..